# Optimizing a symmetric test

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop, computational-geometry

I have n items. For each pair, I have to run a test (True/False). The test is symmetric: test(a,b)=test(b,a). I'm looking the fastest solution to run these tests.

Each item has an id and a property. In this particular case, the property is a polygon shape and I'm looking for the other nearby polygons. This test is symmetric: if A touches B, then B touches A.
Testing twice is redundant. So I wrote this code to test only n(n-1)/2 times:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dict_neigh = defaultdict(list)

# initially my data is in a dataframe, but I though an array would be faster(?) 

# the property of the item:
data=df_gps.coordinates.values

# the index of the item:
ind=df_gps.index.values

end=len(data)
for x in range(0,end-1):
    for y in range(x +1,end):
        # The symmetric test:
        if Polygon(data[x]).touches(Polygon(data[y])):
            # Store the result in a dic
            dict_neigh[ind[x]].append(ind[y])
            dict_neigh[ind[y]].append(ind[x])
```

I would like to know if anybody see a way to improve the speed of this (kind of) test.

Comment: Assuming the method `Polygon.touches` is optimal, the approach is to segregate the polygons in order to reduce the number of comparisons to execute. Some `Polygons` cannot touch another, maybe because they are separated by a line, or too far away from each other, or some other local property... This could possibly be done via a specialized data structure (maybe a quad tree, maybe a grid?), plus some sorting, but will be intimately dependent upon how the objects are represented, and the structure of data itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For this particular problem, you're certainly right. My initial thought was more general, I wandered if my setup was 'correct' (e.g. memory allocation, type of variables - i'm new with python) for this kind of symmetric test.

Comment: @YM'fr: your problem seems to be of an algorithmic nature. Your brute force approach will have a cost roughly proportional to N². It is likely that by means of computational geometry techniques, you could reduce this to N√N or even better. In comparison, the gain that you could hope to get with better "memory allocation, type of variables… (???)" is probably marginal and you shouldn't care.

Comment: You should show sample data set and tell us what you mean by "touching".